# Try to deserialize a XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I have generated with xsd.exe the following class:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class ROOT {

private PersonBaseType pERSONField;

/// <remarks/>
public PersonBaseType PERSON {
    get {
        return this.pERSONField;
    }
    set {
        this.pERSONField = value;
    }
}
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(NotWorkerPersonType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(WorkerPersonType))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public abstract partial class PersonBaseType {

private MotorVehicleType vEHICLEField;

public MotorVehicleType VEHICLE {
    get {
        return this.vEHICLEField;
    }
    set {
        this.vEHICLEField = value;
    }
}
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(CarVehicleType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(AutobusVehicleType))]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public abstract partial class MotorVehicleType {

private string nameField;

public string Name {
    get {
        return this.nameField;
    }
    set {
        this.nameField = value;
    }
}
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class CarVehicleType : MotorVehicleType {
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class AutobusVehicleType : MotorVehicleType {
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class NotWorkerPersonType : PersonBaseType {   
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class WorkerPersonType : PersonBaseType {
}
```

I have generated this class with the tool xsd.exe and the following xsd schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:complexType name="PersonBaseType" abstract="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="VEHICLE" type="MotorVehicleType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="WorkerPersonType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="PersonBaseType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="VEHICLE" type="AutobusVehicleType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="NotWorkerPersonType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="PersonBaseType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="VEHICLE" type="CarVehicleType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="MotorVehicleType" abstract="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="AutobusVehicleType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="MotorVehicleType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="CarVehicleType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="MotorVehicleType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="ROOT">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Root element</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="PERSON" type="PersonBaseType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I try to deserialize this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT xmlns:xxx="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xxx:schemaLocation="C:\Users\SIGFRID\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\sample\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\MySample.xsd">
<PERSON xxx:type="WorkerPersonType">
    <VEHICLE>
        <Name>VOLVO</Name>
    </VEHICLE>
</PERSON>
</ROOT>
```

The Schema Validation is correct and I have not problem, but then I get an `InvalidOperationException` with message:

```
The specified type is abstract: name='MotorVehicleType', Namespace='', bei <VEHICLE xmlns=''>."}
```

I know that I should specify the type of VEHICLE but why the xml pass the schema validation? If the Person element is WorkerPersonType, the VEHICLE can only AutobusVehicleType. That's how I have specified person in xsd schema.

Should I change something of my class? Should I add some attribute or something else?

I have no idea how can i fix this error!

Answer (score 0):

**Three suggestions:**

1. Use `xsi` as the namespace prefix for
   `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.  This is not required
   but is standard.
2. Use the following syntax for local XSDs with spaces in the path:
   `file:///C:/Users/SIGFRID/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202012/Projects/sample/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/MySample.xsd`
3. Use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` rather than `xsi:schemaLocation`
   since you're not using namespaces.

**Here's your XML file with those suggestions applied:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/SIGFRID/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202012/Projects/sample/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/MySample.xsd">
  <PERSON xsi:type="WorkerPersonType">
    <VEHICLE>
      <Name>VOLVO</Name>
    </VEHICLE>
  </PERSON>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunatelly it still doesn't work.I think my generated class with xsd.exe tool is not correct. I read that the xsd.exe tool has limits and doesn't always generate correct classes.

Comment: I fixed some mistakes in my specification of the XSD path above.  Also, I just noticed that there was a full error message in your question -- was lost due to being unformatted.  Edited/fixed in the question.   I notice that you're specifying a non-abstract type for PERSON in the XML but you're not doing so for VEHICLE, which the XSD  defines as being of an abstract type.  The error suggests that this inconsistency must be resolved.

Comment: Yes,I think so as well.But the definition of WorkerPersonType in the XSD contains indirectly the allowed kind of VEHICLE.That's way I think maybe should change anything in my generated class to be able to deserialize the XML. But if it is a inconsistency why do the xml validation pass?

Comment: (1) I'd be reluctant to manually change something in generated code.  (2) I would tend to believe that the XML validation, especially XML validation based from tools based upon Xerces, is correct.  Perhaps you've encountered a limitation of xsd.exe.  Can you accomplish your task without dependence on xsd.exe's proper handling of @xsi:type-driven differentiation of abstract classes (`PERSON`) and the associated implied instantiation of child classes (`VEHICLE`)?